# Pointing devices not properly recognized and won't left/right click after upgrade to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mouse, driver, magic-trackpad

Have loved my Magic Trackpad since it first came out. Since upgrading to Mountain Lion, the system fails to recognize the Trackpad after a reboot. I need to pull the batteries, reload them, and power the Trackpad on... then the Mac sees it. But even then, it won't accept any clicks, it just moves the cursor around. I also tried an old fashioned USB mouse... it needs to be unplugged and plugged back in, but like the Trackpad, that allows cursor movement, but it also won't accept clicks (which makes me believe it is not a Trackpad problem). The machine is a MacPro 3,1 dual quad-core (2008).

My workaround in the meantime is (I think) going to be to remove my wife's user account, then I don't need to click to choose the user. But it is extremely annoying.

Anyone else come across this and have a fix?

Comment: @ProBackup thanks for the edit, but I don't think I'm looking for answers from people who don't know what a Magic Trackpad is. I also don't know what your edit in the title about tablet / mouse mode meant.

Comment: Not all trackpads are Magic Trackpads. A Wacom tablet for instance is a similar input device. Certain Wacom tablet have configuration options where the user can choose its behavior: mouse emulation mode (functioning like a USB mouse) or tablet mode (where the top left of the tablet area corresponds to the top left location of the screen). For instance when the Wacom driver fails to load, the tablet behaves in "mouse mode".

Comment: @ProBackup OK, but can you be more specific? Software Update tells me there is no update available. The system seems to know I have a Magic Trackpad installed. And my system is on the "[OK List](http://forums.appleinsider.com/t/151228/mountain-lion-update-page-confirms-incompatibility-with-older-macs)." So where do I find driver updates? I searched the Apple site but came up empty.

Comment: @ProBackup this is a Magic Trackpad. Where is there any indication that I may be talking about a Wacom tablet?

Comment: You are not talking about a Wacom tablet, but as both Wacom and Magic Trackpad devices are of the same category: "input devices", and of the same subtype "tablets" there are a lot of similarities between these 2 devices. Your answer does not necessarily need to come from a user who knows what a Magic Trackpad is.

Comment: @ProBackup I think we'll have to agree to disagree. The Magic Trackpad does not have any of the settings or configuration options you're talking about, and even if it did, I don't know how such settings could also affect a USB mouse.

Comment: The Magic Trackpad might not have settings, but it behaves like it is depending on a driver. My best guess is that the upgrade to Mountain Lion kept the old Lion driver for the Magic Trackpad. To be sure you could test with a clean Mountain Lion install. When that is the case, the most likely thing that needs to be done is to copy the drive (kext file) from a clean ML installation to the upgraded ML installation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You've demonstrated that the same problem occurs with a normal USB mouse. This is not exclusive to your Magic Trackpad. I think this is a software/settings issue. I have edited the title to (what I believe is) a more accurate description of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Go to System Preferences, then click on Trackpad.  You will have to add the use three fingers to swipe box, as well as unclicking the natural scroll box in the scroll/zoom tab.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: *shrug* I have no idea how this addresses the problem.